# Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT not firing

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I have a certain AutoCAD model that was published to A360 and for some reason I cannot explore the model tree in the Viewer or get the Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT to fire.

When I look in the console, I see 404 Errors returned from https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/items

The model has been uploaded a couple of times, but the problem persists.

Here are sample errors:

> https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/items/urn%3Aadsk.viewing%3Afs.file%3AdXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLndJMjhLUzI5UW1Ld2l3T05TQTV0cUE_dmVyc2lvbj0x%2Foutput%2Fundefined?domain=http%3A%2F%2Fgtpstratus.azurewebsites.net&acmsession=9ed966902dfbb1c7b6586ba01f98291a
>
> https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/items/urn%3Aadsk.viewing%3Afs.file%3AdXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLndJMjhLUzI5UW1Ld2l3T05TQTV0cUE_dmVyc2lvbj0x%2Foutput%2Fobjects_attrs.json?domain=http%3A%2F%2Fgtpstratus.azurewebsites.net&acmsession=9ed966902dfbb1c7b6586ba01f98291a
>
> https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/items/urn%3Aadsk.viewing%3Afs.file%3AdXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLndJMjhLUzI5UW1Ld2l3T05TQTV0cUE_dmVyc2lvbj0x%2Foutput%2Fobjects_vals.json?domain=http%3A%2F%2Fgtpstratus.azurewebsites.net&acmsession=9ed966902dfbb1c7b6586ba01f98291a
>
> https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/items/urn%3Aadsk.viewing%3Afs.file%3AdXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLndJMjhLUzI5UW1Ld2l3T05TQTV0cUE_dmVyc2lvbj0x%2Foutput%2Fobjects_avs.json?domain=http%3A%2F%2Fgtpstratus.azurewebsites.net&acmsession=9ed966902dfbb1c7b6586ba01f98291a
>
> https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/items/urn%3Aadsk.viewing%3Afs.file%3AdXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLndJMjhLUzI5UW1Ld2l3T05TQTV0cUE_dmVyc2lvbj0x%2Foutput%2Fobjects_offs.json?domain=http%3A%2F%2Fgtpstratus.azurewebsites.net&acmsession=9ed966902dfbb1c7b6586ba01f98291a

Comment: I'm investigating a similar report... can you add a print-scree (or copy paste) the 404 errors?

Comment: I've updated my question with the urls that produce 404 errors.  They are from an AutoCAD model.

Comment: thanks! same thing, this problem is already under investigation.

Comment: When viewed inside of our BIM 360 TEAM site, the url is slightly different, but does not give the 404 error:  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/items/urn%3Aadsk.viewing%3Afs.file%3AdXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLndJMjhLUzI5UW1Ld2l3T05TQTV0cUE_dmVyc2lvbj0x%2Foutput%2Fobjects_avs.json.gz?domain=https%3A%2F%2Fgogtp5.autodesk360.com&acmsession=afd2b7a246425a984ec04ed40ac4eb85

Comment: yes, your BIM 360 Team is probably using 2.12 or 2.10 (you can check with LMV_VIEWER_VERSION on the console). You'll see the first 404 has a 'undefined' on it, which causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now (April, 2017) this issue is under investigation on version 2.13/2.14. I would recommend you use [version 2.12](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/2.12/) instead.

Comment: I downgraded to 2.12 and the 404 errors are no longer a problem.